# How to disable startup programs not found in Task Manager and CCleaner?

Tags: task-manager

I have a lot of unnecessary processes that run on startup that I don't want. However, they are not shown on Task Manager > startup or the CCleaner program. How do i manually disable these programs on startup?

Some examples of these unnecessary startup processes are:
Adobe Acrobat update service (armsvc.exe)
Adobe Genuine software service (AGMService.exe)
Adobe Genuine Software Integrity Service (AGSService.exe)

I also have 3 instances of AppVShNotify.exe that ran on startup which I googled, I don't even use virtualization...

(Note that all of these neither show in Task Manager and CCleaner)

I don't want to update Adobe every time i startup my pc. Its just a process thats hogging resource even if there are no updates going on. I do still need Adobe Acrobat Reader but I don't want any of its components such as the above to hog resources on startup.

Comment: Try https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns *Some examples of these unnecessary startup processes are: Adobe Acrobat update service (armsvc.exe) Adobe Genuine software service (AGMService.exe) Adobe Genuine Software Integrity Service (AGSService.exe)* Search them in Task Scheduler.